# Electronjs drag and drop

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, electron

I'm new to electron and want to handle the drag and drop functionality.
Want to drop a file and get its extensions. Based on the extension change something on screen.

i.e. If a .mp3 file was dropped inside want to change the backgroundColor to green and for the .jpg file to be red.

I have managed to use the drag and drop, but don't know how to handle it properly. My code so far is:
**main.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello World!</title>
  </head>
  <body style="color: grey;">
    <div class="character">
      <h1>{nome}</h1>
      <img id="char_anim" src="assets/goku.gif" />
    </div>
  </body>
  <a href="#" id="drag">item</a>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    document.getElementById("drag").ondragstart = (event) => {
      event.preventDefault();
      ipcRenderer.send("ondragstart", "/path/to/item");

    };
  </script>
</html>
```

**main.js**

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require("electron");
const path = require("path");

const MAIN_HTML = path.join("file://", __dirname, "main.html");
const CHILD_PADDING = 50;

const onAppReady = function () {
  let parent = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 1200,
    transparent: false,
    frame: true,
  });

  parent.once("close", () => {
    parent = null;
  });

  parent.loadURL(MAIN_HTML);
};

//~ app.on('ready', onAppReady);
app.on("ready", () => setTimeout(onAppReady, 500));

// dragndrop
ipcMain.on("ondragstart", (event, filePath) => {
  event.sender.startDrag({
    file: filePath,
    icon: "/path/to/icon.png",
  });
});
```

I could explain more, but I just need a way to handle the app to know which extension have this dropped file and display a different message for one or other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main process you can get the file extension using the [`path`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html) module:

```
let ext = require('path').extname(filePath)
```

And then, you can send the returned value to the renderer as follows:

```
event.sender.send('get-file-extension', ext);
```

After that, you can get the sent value use ipcRenderer in order to change the background color:

```
ipcRenderer.on('get-file-extension', (event, extension) => {
     if(extension == '.mp3')
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = "green";
     else if(extension == '.jpg')
          document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
});
```

Comment: Thank you, just a question, the renderer its a js file renderer.js ?

Comment: Yes it is usually put in the end of the main ``html`` file as follows: ``<script src="./renderer.js"></script>``. Please mark the answer as the solution if it solved your problem.

Comment: Do not forget to import ``ipcRenderer`` from ``electron`` in the renderer part

Comment: Don't you have a ``renderer.js`` file? If not, what boilerplate did you use to start the project?

Comment: Note that the first and second sections should be added inside your method in ``main.js`` and the third one in the ``renderer``

Comment: did not have. i created one. in order to add. i used this: https://gitlab.com/doom-fr/electron-transparency-demo

Comment: I think you should use https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start to set up the project for a better architecture.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211485/discussion-between-iago-barreto-and-majed-badawi).